# url rewrite htaccess godaddy or 000webhost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

When I was doing URL rewriting locally it works fine but when I uploaded it, I tried it in GoDaddy and 000webhost but both of them says 404 no found.

I have a domain (GoDaddy) and a sub-folder(completely unrelated to main domain). So I am working in the subdomain only

```
http://maindomain.com/sub/
```

Admin mode was in this url

```
http://maindomain.com/sub/admin/
```

And the controller and action invoked is based on the value after the admin

```
http://maindomain.com/sub/admin/controller/action/
```

This is my .htaccess file (local)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /reoc/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^admin/(.+)$ admin/index.php?URI=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I did a numerous tweaks found in the internet but I gave up with this

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/reoc/admin/(.*)$ %{HTTP_HOST}/reoc/admin/index.php?URI=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The htaccess file is located at the root of the subfolder.

```
maindomain.com
|
`-sub
| |
| `admin
| | |
| | ...
| | `index.php
| |
| `.htaccess
...
```

Comment: Try ^sub/admin....

Comment: I tried it a many time still 404 not found :///

Comment: what happens when the last line is not like "^/reoc" but "^reoc"

Comment: admin/index is also suspicious.. can you print your root folder tree please?

Comment: and is the .htaccess interpreted at all?
I usually check that by putting garbage in the file and check if a error 500 is generated

Comment: @IvoP yes, it does respond to whatever changs I make in the .htaccess file

Comment: And what does your virtual hosts file look like ? Probably in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf

Comment: @EvgenyKolyakov I believe the `sub` is not an official subdomain. I just uploaded it because I do not own the domain. I am just a freeloader

Comment: @EvgenyKolyakov the index file in admin is the main file for admin mode

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: are you accessing the site via reoc.domain.com and is the docroot then in the map maindomain/reoc? Or did you mean your site is running as a subversion of www.domain.com and do you need the /reoc/ in every call to the site?

if the first: then there needs not be any reoc in the url (apart from the domain part)

Comment: I am accessing maindomain/reoc/admin <- this works fine but when I add something like maindomain/reoc/admin/controller/action/ I always get 404 not found

Comment: @IvoP I do have /reoc/ calls for my css and js

Comment: RewriteRule ^/reoc/admin/(.*)$ %{HTTP_HOST}/reoc/admin/index.php?URI=$1 [QSA,L]

I would try
RewriteRule reoc/admin/(.*)$ /reoc/admin/index.php?URI=$1 [QSA,L]

apart from that: Why put the remainer of the url in ?URI=....
index.php can look into $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] or one of the othere elements of $_SERVER to see what the url was and act upon that

Comment: @IvoP please wait Im going to try that now :)))

Comment: Whenever a request something like /reoc/admin/whatever it shall be redirected to /reoc/admin/index.php?URI=whatever. I tried your code but I stil get a 404

Comment: `Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule reoc/admin/(.*)$ /reoc/admin/index.php?URI=$1 [QSA,L]` <- my current htaccess

Comment: I have update my htaccess file with this -->
`RewriteEngine on`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/reoc/admin/(.*)$`

`RewriteRule reoc/admin/(.*)$ /reoc/admin/index.php?URI=$1 [L]`

still 404 not found

Comment: Just to be sure: it s not index.php giving a 404 header for not understanding the given uri or not finding a result?

Comment: what happens if you type the /reoc/admin/index.php?URI=.. url in your browser?

Comment: yes. its not the index but after the /reoc/admin/...
for example /reoc/admin/users : users/ is giving me 404 . its not directing to reoc/admin/index.php

Comment: @IvoP its giving me error 500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would place a file test.php in /reoc/admin/

contents of that file:
`<?php echo __FILE__; echo '<br>' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>`

place a # before the rewrite rules in .htaccess
Check you can access test.php

check /reoc/admin/users indeed give error 404

then in .htaccess
`RewriteRule reoc/admin/users  /reoc/admin/test.php`

indeed, I did not add a wildcard here yet.

If this is working: be sure to add the -f en -d Cond lines before the rule.

now remove the part "users" from the rule.

what are the results?

Comment: the test.php is indeed working. I did a wildcard route earlier actually it did work. Idk why your rewrite rule doesn't work. here is my htaccess file -> `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule reoc/admin/users /reoc/admin/test.php`

Comment: where is this .htaccess file? Can it be placed in the document_root?
because you said subdomein, but as I understand it is just a page inside some map called reoc.

Comment: yeah currently it is placed at the sub. I scared to place it in the main folder as it might affect other subdomains too (which is another systems)

Comment: I tried moving htaccess in the main folder and come up with this -> `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?kikosbakeshop.com$
  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/reoc/admin/
  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /reoc/admin/$1
  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?kikosbakeshop.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ reoc/admin/index.php?URI=$1 [L]` <-- still no good. wew :(((

Comment: what if you add the line RewriteRule reoc/admin/users /reoc/admin/test.php [L]

Comment: OMG! I came up with this rule -> `Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /reoc
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /reoc/admin/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ admin/index.php?URI=$1 [QSA,L]` but the problem is the URI value = 'reoc' it is supposed to be 'users' and beyond heeelp Im so closee! :((

Comment: RewriteRule admin(.*)$ admin/index.php?URI=$1 [QSA,L]

or with a / after admin

Comment: I replaced this RewriteRule admin(.*)?$ admin/index.php?URI=$1 [QSA,L] the value is null ; I added a slash I got error 500 :((

Comment: are the !-f and !-d conditions preceding this rule as well? (rewriteCond are only valid until the next rewriterule)

Comment: I have changed their orders and now I get error 500 `Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /reoc

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/reoc/admin/(.*?)$ [NC]
RewriteRule admin/(.*)$ admin/index.php?URI=$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: I still dont like the rewritebase.  what if you leave out the condition with ^/reoc/admin/(.*?)$. that question mark seem redundant and apart from that, you could also define it as "starts with" widthout saying "and optionally some more characters till the end". But still, this can go into the rule line aswel

Comment: I did your suggestion and come up with `RewriteRule ^/reoc/admin/(.*?)$ reoc/admin/index.php?URI=$1 [QSA,L]` I got 404. :(((

Answer (score 1):

After hours of struggles I managed to breakfree from this stupid problem. And as I suspected. All the URL Rewrites were perfectly executing by the time I was getting an Error 500. The reason I'm getting it is because the spl_autoload_register somehow fails to work. Everythings fine now.

I will just post my final htaccess for those who struggled and will be struggling :)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /subfolder/admin/
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^subfolder/admin/(.*)$ /subfolder/admin/index.php?URI=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Thanks [IvoP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8198537/ivo-p) for all that patience :)